# How to make stub for mongoose document object

Tags: unit-testing, authentication, jestjs, nestjs

I am writing unit test for my auth.service module validateReader unit,

```
async validateReader(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const reader = await this.readerService.findOne(username);
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, reader.password);
    if (match) {
      const { password, ...result } = reader.toJSON();
      this.logger.info(
        `Reader ${reader.username} username & password validation passed`,
      );
      return result;
    }
    this.logger.warn(`Incorrect password in reader ${reader.username} login`);
    return null;
  }
```

I tried to mock readerService.findOne function as following:

```
jest
          .spyOn(readerService, 'findOne')
          .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(readerStub()));
```

but did not work, always got error - Cannot spy the findOne property because it is not a function; I think the reason is the returned value must be mongoose document object (need toJSON() method), but my readerStub() just return a reader object, missing lots of document properties. Is there anyway I can set up stub for document & reader? And maybe my analysis is wrong, there is other reason to got this error.
Following is my mock readerService:

```
export const ReaderService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  register: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  getProfile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  updateProfile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()._id),
  changePwd: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub().username),
  login: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(accessTokenStub()),
  tokenRefresh: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(accessTokenStub()),
  logout: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()._id),
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting up the test with the mocks?

Comment: Just use manual mock: jest.mock('../reader/reader.service'); at beginning of test file, mock file reader.service.ts (last code piece in my message) is in __mocks__ folder same with reader.service.ts file. I used this mock also for reader.service unit test, that test everything works fine

Comment: Interesting. You're able to use the `jest.mock` setup, but usually [I follow the setup in this repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) and use custom providers to make the mocks inside the test

Comment: I checked your repo, find normally you just return required fields not the original query document object from mongoose. So this will make mocking much easier, good experience, I will try that way to see if this can fix my problem.